# Кнопка в DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

Доброго времени суток. К делу: в DataGrid, в таблицу нужно добавить столбик кнопок, это было сделано через DataGridTemplate. Во всех строчках (их n количество) лежит одна и та же кнопка, заранее определенная в коде xaml. При нажатии на нее нужно вернуть номер строчки в которой она находится. Как это можно было бы сделать в коде на с#?

Данным кодом я добавил кнопку в таблицу (xaml):

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>

     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

          <DataTemplate>

               <Button
                  x:Name="bToCorrect"
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                  VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                  Content="" Width="10" Height="10"
                  Click="ToCorrect_Click"
                  />

            </DataTemplate>

      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Так же, таблица имеет свой ItemSource:

```
main.dgTable.ItemsSource = WriteAndRead.ReadForTable(main.Title);
```

Этот код находится в классе решения.

Вот скриншот самой таблицы, то что у меня есть на данный момент: https://ibb.co/kEBpW6. Как вы можете видеть на скриншоте, в каждой строчке есть своя кнопка, но это одна кнопка, продублированная на все строчки. Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку она получала, либо уже содержала в себе номер строчки в которой на нее нажали. Помогите разобраться с этим.

Comment: А вы покажите этот DataGridTemplate и тогда станет яснее, что можно сделать.

Comment: У вас в этом DataGrid некая коллекция отображается? И вы работаете через привязку? И по клику по этой кнопке нам нужно что-то сделать с этим элементом, который выводится в текущей строке?

Comment: Я чуток подкорректировал вопрос, посмотрите еще раз.

Comment: На самом деле мы имеет рваный массив данных, который и является ItemSource для данной таблицы. При нажатии и получении номера строчки мы сможем обратиться к рваному массиву array[N][ ]. Далее в этом массиве я и собираюсь менять содержимое.

Comment: Какой тип возвращает `WriteAndRead.ReadForTable`?

Comment: WriteAndRead.ReadForTable - возвращает рваный массив array[ ][ ].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по вашему XAML `Click="ToCorrect_Click"` вы не пользуетесь командами и MVVM. Потому можно сделать так:

1) назначить имя для `DataGrid`

```
<DataGrid x:Name="_dataGridStations"
```

2) воспользоваться свойством `Tag`

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Button Content="?"
            Width="25"
            Height="25"
            Tag="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=_dataGridStations}"
            Click="Button_Click"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

3) тогда в обработчике можно сделать так

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button button = sender as Button;
    int index = Int32.Parse(button.Tag.ToString());

    MessageBox.Show(index.ToString());
}
```

P.S. у контролов, которые отображают коллекции: `ComboBox, ListBox, DataGrid` есть ряд свойств: `SelectedItem` - выделенный элемент, `SelectedIndex` - индекс выделенного элемента, `ItemsSource` - собственно коллекция-источник для отображения. В третьей строке происходит привязка к свойству кнопки `Tag` индекса выбранного элемента в `DataGrid`. 
Если у вас какие-то проблемы, то где-то вы неправильно скопировали код. Это легко проверить, установите точку останова на строку `int index = Int32.Parse(button.Tag.ToString());` и проверте значение `button.Tag.ToString()`. -1 может говорить о том, что был не выделен элемент в `DataGrid`.

Comment: Поясните как работает третья строчка? Создается кнопка и ей присваивается кнопка?

Comment: И еще у меня всегда выдается -1, где я мог ошибиться по вашему опыту?

Comment: @Kasper смотрите P.S.

Comment: При нажатии на кнопку выделение с элемента таблицы автоматически исчезает. Код переписал точь-в-точь, там ошибки быть не может.

Comment: Не знаю, у меня все работает. Вот [пример](https://yadi.sk/d/YSO0px9r3S4L8i), правда я его изменил на работу через команду.

Comment: Хорошо знаете код, но пример мне не понятен. Расскажите как обойтись одним "Tag"?

Comment: Чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, в integer переменную сохранялось значения индекса строчки, в которой находится кнопка.

Comment: Поработайте с моим примером. Уберите у кнопки `Command` и `CommandParameter` и добавьте ссылку на событие Click, расскоментируйте `private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`. Посмотрите как работает пример. Извините, но больше я ничего вам предложить не могу.

Comment: Вот еще [статейка на Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/270413/).

Comment: Ура! Нашел ошибку. При использовании SelectionUnit="Cell" работать не будет, так же, если стоит "CellOrRowHeader". Благодарю за помощь и за потраченное время.

Comment: @Kasper пожалуйста, очень рад.

Answer (score 1):

Просто воспользуйтесь тем, что любой `ItemsControl` устанавливает своим элементам `DataContext`:

```
int index = ((array[][])dgTable.ItemsSource).IndexOf((array[])((Button)sender).DataContext);
```